# How to get distinct of multiple attributes of a list class in Java using streams API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have class Address as below:

```
class Address {
    String address;
    String phone1;
    String phone2;

    getters & setters
}
```

My requirement is to get the distinct of phone1 and phone2 from a list of Address.
I could get the result below. But is there any better way to get the result

```
    Address add1 = new Address("NAME1", null, null);
    Address add2 = new Address("NAME2", "123", null);
    Address add3 = new Address("NAME3", null, "456");

    List<Address> addressList = Arrays.asList(add1, add2, add3);

    Set<String> distinctPhoneNo = addressList.stream()
            .filter(add -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(add.getPhone1()))
            .map(Address::getPhone1)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    distinctPhoneNo.addAll(addressList.stream()
            .filter(add -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(add.getPhone2()))
            .map(Address::getPhone2)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

The expected result is `["123", "456"]`

Comment: This question should be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a little simplified with mapping address into stream of two phones (`.distinct()` is not necessary as it's collected into `Set`):

```
 Set<String> distinctPhoneNo = addressList.stream()
            .flatMap(address -> Stream.of(address.getPhone1(), address.getPhone2()))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or with list:

```
 List<String> distinctPhoneNo = addressList.stream()
            .flatMap(address -> Stream.of(address.getPhone1(), address.getPhone2()))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```